# 2 images with same src, one renders, one doesn't. How?

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat, backbone.js, path

i have 2 img tags with the same src, `"images/export.png"`. One of them shows correctly, while the other one doesn't. Anyone have any idea how this can happen?

[image]

Some context:

-Using Backbone.js, with pushState enabled. So internal app navigation is done through "/location" instead of hashes "#location".

-Context root is `localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator`

-The working image is hardcoded in index.html, while the broken one is inserted into the DOM by javascript.

-The "New Products" tab is currently the default page, so `localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator` will call `localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator/NewProducts`. I've found that the broken image will work when I go to `localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator/NewProducts` but not `localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator`, even though the destination page is the same, `localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator/index.html`. This makes me think it's some local/relative pathing problem.

-In fact, when the url is `localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator`, every single script src thinks the base uri is `localhost:8080`. Yet all the js still runs, even though when I open `localhost:8080/js/index.js` it gives me 404. Which is true, because all js files are under `localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator/js`. But then why is the js still executing? I've cleared my browser history/cached files many times. Why is the base uri set as `localhost:8080` when the html doc is at `localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator/index.html`. Shouldn't the base uri be `localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator`?

-If i right click "view image in new tab", both the working image and broken image gives 404 not found. This makes sense because the image path is `"localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator/images/export.png"` and the img src tries to access `"localhost:8080/images/export.png".`It makes no sense that the working image, works at all..

I have no idea what's going on, it seems to be some caching/path issue that is exacerbated by localhost issues.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState:true,root:"/NewBizGenerator"});
```

to

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState:true,root:"/NewBizGenerator/"});
```

I guess without the end slash, all resources tried to go to `localhost:8080` instead of `localhost:8080/NewBizGenerator`

Comment: No guess necessary: that's how the web works. If you use relative links, you'd better be sure what they are relative *to*.